# Oracle DML statement file - Execute, Record error and continue without aborting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a file with `INSERTs`, `UPDATEs`, `DELETEs`. I want to execute each of the DML statements in this file, but in case any exception occurs, I want to print that exception and continue. Is there a simple solution for this? Below is a solution which involves wrapping **each** DML in an anonymous block and print the exception, but I think it is not simple (or elegant) enough:

```
BEGIN
  <<DML statement goes here>>
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
END;
```

Needless to say, this cannot be done (easily) for hundreds of DMLs.

Comment: Put all your statements in a collection, then loop over the collection and use execute immediate?  Why would you want to have a 1/2-baked set of transactions though?  Is each DML independent of the others?

Comment: @OldProgrammer That still sounds tedious to me. You are correct, each DML is independent of others that I do NOT care if they fail. I only want to just know which ones failed so that I can take corrective action later.

Comment: Put the statement in a string and then execute the string: EXECUTE('INSERT TABLE ....').  This will allow the process to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible decision is to add error logging clause to your statements. To each of your statement you have to add following (for example for `INSERT`):

```
insert into my_table (...)
values (...)
LOG ERRORS INTO err$_my_table ('INSERT') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Here `err$_my_table` is a table for error logging. To create it, execute (once per table) following:

```
begin
  DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG ('MY_TABLE');
end;
/
```

Error logging clause suppresses any exception and put in error logging table all lines, which fired exceptions. After executing you can query these tables. They will also contain values of `SQLCODE` and `SQLERRM` functions. Disadvantages of this method - you need to change all your statements and create a logging table for each table.
More about clause in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#BGBDIGAH).